How to remove the rest of the text after CSS ellipsis
The text is truncated by CSS rules text-overflow: ellipsis; and overflow: hidden; but when the text is longer and goes to next row, sometimes the next row is showing few pixels. element.innerHTML doesn't show the three dots from ellipsis, so I can't detect it with regex and remove it.
How can I remove the remaining text from html element after ellipsis is added?
In the example the height of the div should stay the same


let ele = document.getElementById('header-inner');

ele.innerHTML = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which  ';
#header-inner {
height: 80px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  max-height: 62px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  white-space: unset;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  padding-top: 0px;

        }
<div id='header-inner'></div>




Can you please provide the HTML and CSS code which produces the issue. Also the image seems to be showing the actual problem..?

white-space: nowrap to prevent line-breaks in the first place? Why do you need JS?

Any ideas about case with multiple lines using ellipsis?

From your description, I see no reason to try to solve the issue with JS. Simply solve it on CSS level by using white-space: nowrap


let ele = document.getElementById('header-inner');

ele.textContent = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which ';
#header-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 461px;
  max-height: 29px;
  min-height: 25px;
  
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div id='header-inner'></div>




Yes, that works, but sometimes I have more css styling added to the element and with them and white-space: nowrap the ellipsis doesn't work. I edited my code snippet

the issue there is display: -webkit-box; which is not a valid value. Despite that, it would make no sense to try to only address webkit browsers. If you remove the line, it will work perfectly

Very similar problem when ellipsis is on second or third line, depending on font size and line height, sometimes the rest of the text is showing.
